# Save output of each command inside for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I need to save the output for each command inside the for loop. My code is given below but it is not saving the log files.

```
count=60
for d in /afs/cern.ch/user/r/rasharma/work/TBA/Data/Run06*
do
        echo $d
        echo "./shrd51_EventBuilderVFAT.sh $d"
        ./shrd51_EventBuilderVFAT.sh $d | tee $count_EventBuilder.log
        echo "./shrd51_TrackFinder.sh $d"
        ./shrd51_TrackFinder.sh $d | tee $count_TrackFinder.log
        echo "./shrd51_Analyzer.sh $d 0$count"
        ./shrd51_Analyzer.sh $d 0$count | tee $count_Analyzer.log
        count=$((count+1))
done
```

Comment: Use `tee -a` to append.

Comment: And if you are appending, you may want to clear out (empty) your files at the start of the script somewhere with `> file`

Comment: @thatotherguy not working. And I don't need to append. Whenever I will run this I need to recreate a new file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't need to append. Also I tried ">" instead of "| tee" but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `$count_Analyzer.log` is expanded like `${count_Analyzer}.log`, that is, the value of the variable `count_Analyzer` followed by the string `.log`. Since that variable doesn't exist, you'll have a *hidden* file `.log` with *all* the output.

You want `${count}_Analyzer.log`.

Good luck finding particles!